# MS Access, Calculating between rows in a table

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to calculate rows within an MS Access table. This is basically a running budget. I'm taking the balance from the previous day, adding "amounts in" from the current day and then subtracting "amounts out" from the current day, the result is the current day's new balance. This is super simple in Excel, but I'm stumped on how to do this in Access.

Simple table shown below. The calculation will be done in the Balance field.

| Date | Amount In | Amount Out | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11-1 | 100 | 0 | `100` |
| 11-2 | 0 | 50 | `=100+0-50=50` |
| 11-3 | 200 | 100 | `=50+200-100=150` |

The table is not showing correctly in the post, I added a screen shot below.

[image]:

Comment: Access's SQL engine is permanently stuck in the year ~1997: i.e. it only supports a subset of SQL-92, and zero new SQL features introduced since then, including window-functions which is what you need to effectively compute a running sum or balance in a query. You can still accomplish what you're after using VBA (by manually iterating over rows), but not by using SQL alone.

Answer (score 3):

Try below co-related query.

```
SELECT t2.*, 
(select Sum(t1.AmountIn) - Sum(t1.AmountOut) from Table1 as t1 where t1.tDate<=t2.tDate) AS Balance
FROM Table1 AS t2;
```

[image]

Comment: Can I see what the query looks like in Design View?

Comment: Put the SQL to a new query SQL view and then switch back to design view.